# Wordpress custom page attribute

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm working on a custom WP theme that displays all "pages" as sections in a one page layout.

What I would like to do is add a color chooser to the page designer, so that the user can choose a color to be the background color of that section.

I'm totally new to wordpress so I don't even know what files or functions to look at to add this behavior.

Is there perhaps a prebuilt plugin to do something like this?

Comment: That depends, are you developing the theme or simply installing it in a site?

Comment: I'm making a custom theme for my custom site, it's not really meant to be a general theme.

Answer (score 2):

Four options:

- use a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) or [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/)
- ACF has a [Lite version](https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf-lite) to add the meta box programmatically
- a helper script like [Custom Metaboxes and Fields for WordPress](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress)
- do it yourself, using this Q&A as example: [Add a checkbox to post screen that adds a class to the title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/61041/12615)

Probably, you'd want to change the visibility of the meta box according to the chosen page template, refer to this Q&A: [Custom meta box shown when template is chosen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50092/12615)